# Heroku Push, pip installs wrong versions

Tags: django, heroku, pip

I'm attempting to push my application to Heroku. Everything works locally. When pushing pip runs and installs things, and the push finishes. Looking back through the push output though, there are a lot of incorrectly installed packages. Such as:

```
Downloading/unpacking python-dateutil==2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
     Running setup.py egg_info for package python-dateutil

     Requested python-dateutil==2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22)), but installing version 2.0
Downloading/unpacking South==0.7.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
     Running setup.py egg_info for package South

     Requested South==0.7.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24)), but installing version 0.7.3
```

This breaks functionality of collectstatic (in dateutils case) as well as our entire app (in django-registration and others cases). How can I get this to install the proper/requested versions? I tried installing directly from tarballs but it downloads the new version, uninstalls the old, and reinstalls the old.

**UPDATE:**

As a temporary fix, I changed the runtime Python version so all applications would be uninstalled, then changed it back and used tarball links to install the right versions. I would still like to find a solution that allows for normal pip installation/versioning.

Comment: What does your `requirements.txt` file look like?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/878062/
Tried it with both the normal module==version and the tarballs.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, when something like this happens to me, it's because I have forgotten to switch the proper virtual env (using virtualenv.py), and I'm using the wrong requirements.txt.

Comment: Neither is the case here unfortunately.